# How to make header of bootstrap table fixed using inline css?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm trying to create a sortable table with a fixed header using bootstrap template. The css file of bootstrap is to complicated so I'm looking for a way to make the header of my table fixed by using inline css.

This is what i got so far:

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 3%;">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex align-items-stretch" style="height: 650px; overflow: auto;">
        <table id="dtDynamicVerticalScrollExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Company
                </th>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    URL
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>

            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApiRedirectID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Company.CompanyName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApiName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ApiURL2)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ApiRedirectID }) |
                        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ApiRedirectID })
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I've tried using the position attribute with inline css like this:

```
<tr style="position:fixed">
```

This will result in the following:

[image]

Hope someone knows a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try position:sticky

Comment: Does not work, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }
```

full e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/